# Proof of subfield criterion

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields

I was reading a proof about the uniqueness of each subfield of any given order and came across a line in the proof I couldn't understand.

[Theorem 6.7](http://www.math.rwth-aachen.de/~Max.Neunhoeffer/Teaching/ff/ffchap3.pdf)

> Let $F_q$ be the finite field with $q = p^n$
>   elements. Then every subfield of $F_q$ has order $p^m$, where m is
>   a positive divisor of n. Conversely, if m is a positive divisor of n, then there is exactly one subfield
>   of $F_q$ with $p^m$ elements

**Proof**

> Clearly, a subfield K of F must have order $p^m$ for some positive integer $m ≤ n.$ By Lemma 6.1, q = $p^n$ must be a power of p
>   m, and so m must divide n.
>
> Conversely, if m is a positive divisor of n, then $p^{
> m −1}$ divides $p
> ^{n −1}$, and so $x^{p^m−1} −1$ divides
>   $x^{p^n−1} −1$ in $F_p[x]$. So, every root of $x^{p^m}−x$ is a root of $x^{p^n} −x$, and hence belongs to $F_q$. It follows
>   that $F_q$ must contain a splitting field of $x^
> {p^m}
> − x$ over $F_p$ as a subfield, and (from proof of Theorem
>   6.5) such a splitting field has order $p^
> m$. If there were two distinct subfields of order $p^
> m$ in $F_q$, they
>   would together contain more than $p^m$ roots of $x^{p^m}
> − x$ in $F_q$, a contradiction.

The difficulty I'm having with the proof lies in this sentence:

> if m is a positive divisor of n, then $p^{
> m −1}$ divides $p
> ^{n −1}$, and so $x^{p^m−1} −1$ divides
>   $x^{p^n−1} −1$ in $F_p[x]$.

I'm not sure how $p^{m-1}|p^{n-1}$ and how $x^{p^m−1} −1|x^{p^n−1} −1$ follows from this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've copied the text down incorrectly: it says $p^m-1$ divides $p^n-1$, **not** $p^{m-1}$ divides $p^{n-1}$ (even though that is also a true statement).

> [image]

There is a general fact, which is easy to prove: if $a\mid b$, then $x^a-1$ divides $x^b-1$, since
$$x^b-1=(x^a)^k-1^k=(x^a-1)((x^a)^{k-1}+(x^a)^{k-2}+\cdots+(x^a)+1)$$
So since $m\mid n$, we can apply this fact to get that $p^m-1$ divides $p^n-1$, and then applying that same fact again, we get $x^{p^m-1}-1$ divides $x^{p^n-1}-1$.